# Right approach to interpretation of linear regression with logarithm

Tags: regression, interpretation, panel-data

I have a panel regression that includes several individuals. I run regression. Here, the model looks approximately like this:

$$
\log(Consumption) \sim  \beta _{1}\log(Price)+\beta _{2}\cdot x_1 + \beta_{3} \cdot a 
$$
where x is marketing influence
and a is dummy when the week had holidays or special dates.

As I understand right, the $\beta_1$ will show the elasticity, and I can interpret that increase in price by 1% affects the consumption by $\beta_1$%.
But how to interpret $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$? Should I take $\exp(\beta_2)$?